# matlab coder - function with 'char switch'

Tags: matlab, octave

Is something like this:

```
function [rv] = get_bla(m)
%#codegen
assert(isa(m,'char'));
assert(size(m, 1) >= 1);
assert(size(m, 1) <= 1024);

switch m
    case 'xyz' 
        rv = 1;
    case 'xyz1'   
        rv = 2; 
    otherwise
        error('Unexpected something');
end
```

actually possible in the context of the matlab coder?

I am using:

```
codegen -config:dll get_bla
```

and get:

SWITCH expression has indeterminate size.

As 'char arrays' have to be of static size for C/C++, I presume the above is impossible or is there a work around?

Comment: Try `if`-`else if` statements instead of `switch`

Comment: Actually trying this at the moment. Thanks. Guess I have to use strcmpi ...?

Comment: where does `material` comes from? If material is a string it should work (at least does in Octave). But if you want to make a case insensitive comparison, use `switch tolower (material)`

Comment: sorry - i made a mistake whilst simplifying the code material -> m

Comment: @Praetorian - can you please post an answer? This helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `if`-`elseif` statements instead of the `switch` statement.

```
if strcmp(m, 'xyz')
  rv = 1;
elseif strcmp(m, 'xyz1')
  rv = 2;
else
  error('unexpected');
end
```